# MSSQL Sort order in Stored procedure or Query not preserved when result is output using asp or php

Tags: sql-server, asp-classic

We have web application written in classic asp uses SQLOLEDB to connect to the MSSQL database. we recently upgraded from SQL 2000 to SQL 2008 R2.
If I set the sort order in stored procedure or Query and then output in asp, record set data shows up in some random sort order - before with SQL 2000 it worked correctly

For example: I have the followin SQL statement either in view or stored procedure

```
SELECT ID, NAME FROM dbo.MyTable ORDER BY Name ASC
```

When I run this in query analyser, sort order is correct
but when I output in asp, its randomly sorted

Not sure, what changed, any help is appreciated

Thanks,
Kris

Comment: Can you please post some code - how SP/query is called and how results are displayed?

Comment: What is the `random sort order` ?

Comment: can you show how you are outputting in asp ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code that calls the SP/View must be applying a sort to it, or your datagrid is sorted.  The results your get from SQL Server will be in "Name ASC" order.  What your code does with it from there is another story.

Try this for verification, set a breakpoint right after you fill your dataset/datatable/whatever and inspect it with  the debugger. If it is a dataset/datatable, the debugger has built in viewers for these formats (and others) so you can see your data in a grid.

The only other thing it could be is the collation order was set wrong when you installed SQL Server.

Comment: Correct me of I'm wrong, but he is using Classic ASP (vbScript), not ASP.NET

Comment: Thanks Steve, there was collation issue and also the use SQL TOP 100 PERCENT - I changed it to SELECT TOP 100000 and not it works

Comment: Unless you only want the top 100000, you should not include that part of the SQL. Instead of `SELECT TOP 100000 Field1,Field1, ...` try `SELECT Field1,Field1, ...` for all records.